# Recently Viewed showing 404 Not found URL for Prodcuts of other stores

Tags: multistore, 404

I have two stores City 1 and City 2 under a same website instance of Magento. I have created two separate categories as city1 and city2. Both these categories have individual sub category "phones" and each sub category has products which are distinctly unique to that category (meaning product assigned to city 1 will not be assigned anywhere in city 2 and vice a versa). Lets say I am in City 1 and viewed details of one of the product (lets say product A). In my recently viewed products I can see Product A is appearing. I change my city to city 2. Still I continue to see Product A. When I click on the product, I get 404 Not found.

I am ok if the product is shows up when I click on the product in recently viewed. To enable this feature, I changed the visibility of store view of city1 as catalog,search and changed the visibility of product A in store view city2 as catalog. This solves the problem of viewing the product from recently viewed.

The next problem is when I click on the product A from City 2, The breadcrumbs shows home/City1/Phones/phonename. If i click on City1 or Phones from that breadcrumbs, i again get 404 not found. Here I am completely lost as to what should be the solution.

Please help!

I am using Magento 1.9

Comment: When you switch the store, it should redirect to home page of selected store. This way you can easily overcome these problems.

Comment: Thanks programmer_rtk, however I have even observed that when I visit the phones section of City 2, and just revisit the same recently viewed product, the breadcrumbs shows home/phonename. The storename and phone links disappear all together. Can this be considered as Magento Bug ? What you suggested surely helps me for the case I described. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest solution for this problem is to redirect to corresponding store's home page, when a store switching happens.

What is the problem right now is, you are staying on the same page even if you have switched to another store view. Due to this when you click on old links that are correspond to another store view, then you will get a 404 page. So you need to redirect user whenever he is making a store switching.

Regarding your second comment :- I dont think its a magento bug. May be recent viewed products are not filtering based on the current store. Due to this you are obtaining recently viewed products in global scope. So you need to make sure everything that is  loading in a page is strictly that of current store that you are viewing.

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks I will take that as an answer. Thanks :)